# How to avoid long switches

Tags: c#, wpf, oop

I have a table

```
ID Name
1  New York
2  California
3  Maine
4  Ohio
5  Washington
```

I can find the match based on the ID that the user will pass in.

However I want to be able to call a WPF view based on the ID that was passed in.

How can I avoid writing a long switch statement?

Comment: without knowing your data structures thats impossible to answer

Comment: What do you mean calling a WPF view based on the ID? Is it completely a different view? Or can you delegate the composition of that view to the view itself and pass the ID as a parameter?

Comment: Using a static **map/dictionary**. Adding a **second column** in DB. Decorating your **views with an attribute** for that metadata (and with a touch of reflection). Using some **conventions about naming**. Using multiple **IFs** intead of switch. **What you tried?**

Comment: Make a Dictionary<int,View> dictionary=new Dictionary<int,View>();
dictionary.Add(1,new NewYorkView());
....
dictionary[ID].Show(); 
kind of

Comment: I would be calling NewYorkView, CaliforniaView, etc...  If I create a Doctionary<int,View> as suggested should this be populated from the DB?  Right now there is no association created between ID and the view that is needed.

Comment: No, it can't be populated from db unless you use some convention (for example: view name is state name without spaces with "View" suffix) but if you have that convention then you don't need a dictionary. Then: 1) populate dictionary "by hand" (or with a specific column name in DB) or 2) don't use a dictionary and use a convention or 3) one of the other methods (for example a proper attribute to decorate each view and then some reflection to find them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question, but if you need to be able to call specific views for specific cities, it may be easiest to store that information in your data. You could add a column to your cities table or create another table to join to that will contain whether or not the city should get a custom view. From there, use reflection to spin up the view you need.

Comment: I create a cross table with the ID and the viewname.  So if a view changes in the future it will be a simple db change.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<int,View> dictionary=new Dictionary<int,View>();
dictionary.Add(1,new NewYorkView());
dictionary.Add(2,new California());
```

or simply a list

```
Type[] viewTypes=new Type[null,typeof(NewYorkView),typeof(CaliforniaView),,,,,];
```

and when you receive the ID:

```
dictionary[ID].Show();
```